# C# Blazor This works but I am getting errors

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, blazor

Maybe I am doing something wrong or maybe VisualStudio is acting up please advise...

The Error is:

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0115  'TechProfile.OnInitializedAsync()': no suitable method found to override
```

The program works as intended but I don't want errors popping up if they are true errors. please advise also if anyone knows a way to ViewModel the Blazored.LocalStorage based on my code I would love to know a way to put it in a separate cs file and call it once rather than keep setting it.

Ok here is my razor component

```
@page "/profile/techprofile/techinfo"
@using TechHelper.Model
@inherits TechModel
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService oLocalStore
 
<h3>Technician Profile</h3>


    <table id="TechProfile" class="ProfileTable">

        <thead colspan="2"> Profile Information </thead>

        <tr>
            <td>Full Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="TechName" class="inputfield" @bind-value="@TechName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Standard ID: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="StandardID" class="inputfield" @bind-value="@TechID" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email Address: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="TechEmail" class="inputfield" @bind-value="@TechEmail" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="TechPhoneNumber" class="inputfield" @bind="@TechPhoneNumber" />
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div align="center"><input class="techSubmit" type="button" 
@onclick="SaveProfile" value ="Save Profile Information" /></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<span>@Message</span>


@code {
 
string Message = "";

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    TechName = await oLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("TechnicianName");
    TechID = await oLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("TechnicianID");
    TechPhoneNumber = await oLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("TechnicianPhoneNumber");
    TechEmail = await oLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("TechnicianEmail");
}

public async void SaveProfile()
{
    Message = "Profile Data Saved";
    await oLocalStore.SetItemAsync("TechnicianName", TechName);
    await oLocalStore.SetItemAsync("TechnicianID", TechID);
    await oLocalStore.SetItemAsync("TechnicianPhoneNumber", TechPhoneNumber);
    await oLocalStore.SetItemAsync("TechnicianEmail", TechEmail);
}
}
```

And this is my TechModel.cs - i added the = ""; because of the error trying to see if it would shut it up.

```
public class TechModel
{
    public string TechName { get; set; } = "";
    public string TechID { get; set; } = "";
    public string TechPhoneNumber { get; set; } = "";
    public string TechEmail { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your component is descending from `TechModel` which does not directly or indirectly descend from ComponentBase, so there is no method to override.